# Brute force method algorithm python

Tags: python

I want to get the addition of set with all possible combination using brute force method and get the highest modulus value of a given number.

The given number to find modulus is n: 7

For example:

I/P:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[1,3,8,4,9]]
```

O/P :

```
1+3+1 = 5
1+3+3 = 8
1+3+8 = 12
.
.
1+4+1 = 6
1+4+3 = 8
.
.
2+3+1 = 6
2+3+3 = 8
.
.
```

All possible combination

Expected O/P :

```
1+4+1 = 6
6%7 = 6
```

The highest modulus in the set that can be achieved is 6 (n-1)

Comment: Please share expected output. Are all additions between three digits? Please elaborate

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: @yatu yes all the addition are 3 digit's obtained from the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done with a `for` loop, after getting the length of each of the lists and using that as the count.

```py
list1 = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[1,3,4,8,9]]
length1 = len(list1[0])
length2 = len(list1[1])
length3 = len(list1[2])

for a in range(0,length1):
    for b in range(0,length2):
        for c in range(0,length3):
            print(list1[0][a] + list1[1][b] + list1[2][c])
```

What this does is take the length of each sublist, then iterates over that length, and prints the result.

To then modulo the answer and find the biggest modulus, you'd need to put that inside the third for loop, aka:

```py
max = 0 #this should be outside all of the for loops

        for c in range(0,length3):
            result = list1[0][a] + list1[1][b] + list1[2][c]
            if result % 7 > max:
                max = result % 7
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Apologies, I was doing lua indexes - will update in 30 seconds.

Comment: The code works fine but i want to achieve only the max modulus from all the numbers.

Comment: i want to put all the modulus value in a list .

Comment: All of the modulus values? Including duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Simple bruteforce:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[1,3,8,4,9]]

highest_modulus = 0
for i in my_list[0]:
    for j in my_list[1]:
        for k in my_list[2]:
            res = i + j + k
            print(f"{i}+{j}+{k} = {res}")
            if res % 7 > highest_modulus:
                highest_modulus = res

print(f"{highest_modulus}%7 = {highest_modulus % 7}")
```

Output:

```
1+3+1 = 5
1+3+3 = 7
1+3+8 = 12
1+3+4 = 8
1+3+9 = 13
1+4+1 = 6
1+4+3 = 8
1+4+8 = 13
1+4+4 = 9
1+4+9 = 14
2+3+1 = 6
2+3+3 = 8
2+3+8 = 13
2+3+4 = 9
2+3+9 = 14
2+4+1 = 7
2+4+3 = 9
2+4+8 = 14
2+4+4 = 10
2+4+9 = 15
3+3+1 = 7
3+3+3 = 9
3+3+8 = 14
3+3+4 = 10
3+3+9 = 15
3+4+1 = 8
3+4+3 = 10
3+4+8 = 15
3+4+4 = 11
3+4+9 = 16
4+3+1 = 8
4+3+3 = 10
4+3+8 = 15
4+3+4 = 11
4+3+9 = 16
4+4+1 = 9
4+4+3 = 11
4+4+8 = 16
4+4+4 = 12
4+4+9 = 17
13%7 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `product` from the itertools package.

```py
from itertools import product

z = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[1,3,8,4,9]]

list(map(lambda x: '{}+{}+{} = {}'.format(*x, sum(x)), product(*z)))
# returns:
['1+3+1 = 5',
 '1+3+3 = 7',
 '1+3+8 = 12',
 '1+3+4 = 8',
 '1+3+9 = 13',
 '1+4+1 = 6',
 '1+4+3 = 8',
 '1+4+8 = 13',
 '1+4+4 = 9',
 '1+4+9 = 14',
 '2+3+1 = 6',
 '2+3+3 = 8',
 '2+3+8 = 13',
 '2+3+4 = 9',
 '2+3+9 = 14',
 '2+4+1 = 7',
 '2+4+3 = 9',
 '2+4+8 = 14',
 '2+4+4 = 10',
 '2+4+9 = 15',
 '3+3+1 = 7',
 '3+3+3 = 9',
 '3+3+8 = 14',
 '3+3+4 = 10',
 '3+3+9 = 15',
 '3+4+1 = 8',
 '3+4+3 = 10',
 '3+4+8 = 15',
 '3+4+4 = 11',
 '3+4+9 = 16',
 '4+3+1 = 8',
 '4+3+3 = 10',
 '4+3+8 = 15',
 '4+3+4 = 11',
 '4+3+9 = 16',
 '4+4+1 = 9',
 '4+4+3 = 11',
 '4+4+8 = 16',
 '4+4+4 = 12',
 '4+4+9 = 17']
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without package?

Comment: Yes.  `itertools` is part of the standard library through, so if you have Python, you have itertools.

Comment: a = list(map(lambda x: '{}+{}+{} = {}'.format(*x, sum(x)), product(*z)))                                                                                  
                                                     ^                                                                                                        
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  This works for 3.4+